# WordPress: Trash Custom Post Type after 30 days

Tags: php, wordpress, cron, custom-post-type

I want to trash (not force delete) a Custom Post Type after 30 days.
To do this, I've found a nice solution from @pieter-goosen to delete posts after a number of days: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/209046/delete-expired-posts-after-a-number-of-days-after-they-expired

My problem is, that the function deletes all the posts of this Custom Post Type and doesn't use the trash.

My code looks like this:

```
function get_exired_posts_to_delete()
{
    /**
     * If you need posts that expired more than a week ago, we would need to
     * get the unix time stamp of the day a week ago. You can adjust the relative
     * date and time formats as needed.
     * @see http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php
     * @see http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php
     */
    // As example, we need to get posts that has expired more than 7days ago
    $past = strtotime( "- 1 week" );

    // Set our query arguments
    $args = [
        'fields'         => 'ids', // Only get post ID's to improve performance
        'post_type'      => 'job',
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'date_query'    => array(
            'column'  => 'post_date_gmt',
            'before'   => '30 days'
        )
    ];
    $q = get_posts( $args );

    // Check if we have posts to delete, if not, return false
    if ( !$q )
        return false;

    // OK, we have posts to delete, lets delete them
    foreach ( $q as $id )
        wp_delete_post( $id );
}

// expired_post_delete hook fires when the Cron is executed
add_action( 'expired_post_delete', 'get_exired_posts_to_delete' );

// Add function to register event to wp
add_action( 'wp', 'register_daily_post_delete_event');
function register_daily_post_delete_event() {
    // Make sure this event hasn't been scheduled
    if( !wp_next_scheduled( 'expired_post_delete' ) ) {
        // Schedule the event
        wp_schedule_event( time(), 'daily', 'expired_post_delete' );
    }
}
```

Is there anythin wrong with the date query?

And is there a better solution to use the server cron instead the WP cron?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for my question.

For the problem with the trash, I've changed the argument wp_delete_post() to wp_trash_post() because wp_delete_post() only applies to native posts, pages, and attachments. Great answer from @rarst here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/281877/error-after-deleting-custom-post-type-with-a-function-no-trash-used/281888#281888

Here is my code:

```
function get_delete_old_jobs() {
    // Set our query arguments
    $args = [
        'fields'         => 'ids', // Only get post ID's to improve performance
        'post_type'      => 'job',
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'date_query'    => array(
            'before' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-30 days'))
        )
    ];
    $q = get_posts( $args );

    // Check if we have posts to delete, if not, return false
    if ( !$q )
        return false;

    // OK, we have posts to delete, lets delete them
    foreach ( $q as $id )
        wp_trash_post( $id );
}

// expired_post_delete hook fires when the Cron is executed
add_action( 'old_job_delete', 'get_delete_old_jobs' );


// Add function to register event to wp
add_action( 'wp', 'register_daily_jobs_delete_event');

function register_daily_jobs_delete_event() {
    // Make sure this event hasn't been scheduled
    if( !wp_next_scheduled( 'old_job_delete' ) ) {
        // Schedule the event
        wp_schedule_event( time(), 'hourly', 'old_job_delete' );
    }
}
```